# Magento 2 - Loading an Order through API

Tags: magento2, orders, api, rest-api, magento-2.1.9

We need to call API's in order to get order details. We are doing so in a dev environment. What happens is that we are not calling any order by the `"order_id"`, instead we use the `entity_id`.

```
<web>/rest/V1/orders/8
```

We instead want to use:

```
<web>/rest/V1/orders/086190004
```

Is that possible? In the Magento docs it says:

[image]

We want to be able to load these orders by the `order_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done.

I used:

> allyourweb/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=#orderNumber#&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

Hope it helps all of you.